# Show a set must be measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Below is a problem I found, however, after many attemps I can not seem to get a solution.

**Problem:** Let $E \subset [0,1]$. Show that if $m^*(E) + m^*([0,1] \setminus E) = 1$, then $E$ is measurable.

(my attempted) **Solution:** Notice, the following is true $[0,1] \setminus E = [0,1] \cap E^c$. Therefore, we can rewrite the given equations as

$$m^*(E) + m^*([0,1] \cap E^c) = 1. \quad (i)$$

Also, notice that $E = [0,1] \cap E$, hence, we can rewrite $(i)$ as the following

$$m^*([0,1] \cap E) + m^*([0,1] \cap E^c) = 1. \quad (ii)$$

Since $m^*([0,1]) = 1$ we can, again, rewrite $(ii)$ as follows

$$m^*([0,1] \cap E) + m^*([0,1] \cap E^c) = m^*([0,1]). \quad (iii)$$

For this path, this is where I get stuck. In other words, obviously if $[0,1]$ could be replaced by any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ then, sure, $E$ is measurable. Therefore, I do not think this is the "correct path" to take.

I feel like one way is, possibly, to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a closed set F, such that, $E \subseteq F$ and $m^*(F \setminus E) < \epsilon$. Taking $F = [0,1]$, we have $E \subset F$ and
$m^*(F \setminus E) < 1 - m^*(E)$. Hence, if I take $\epsilon = 1 - m^*(E)$ can I conclude the proof?

Comment: What do you mean when you write “$m^*$”? You mean the Lebesgue outer measure, do not you?

Comment: @Angelo Yes, $m^*$ is denoting the Lebesgue Outer Measure.

Comment: If you use the Lebesgue inner measure “$m_*$”, the equality $(i)$ is equivalent to $m^*(E)=m_*(E)$ and it implies that $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Look at this http://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/talks/Measure-Theory.pdf

Comment: @Angelo Thank you. That does look interesting.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be any Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0,1]$. So, Lebesgue measurability of $A$ gives $$m^*(E)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A^c\cap E)$$ and $$m^*(E^c)=m^*(A\cap E^c)+m^*(A^c\cap E^c).$$
Adding these two we have, $$m^*([0,1])=m^*(E)+m^*(E^c)$$$$=\bigg[m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c)\bigg]+\bigg[m^*(A^c\cap E)+m^*(A^c\cap E^c)\bigg]$$$$\geq m^*(A)+m^*(A^c)\geq m^*([0,1]).$$ Both inequalitities are due to the fact $m^*$ is sub-additive. Hence, $$m^*(A)+m^*(A^c)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c)+m^*(A^c\cap E)+m^*(A^c\cap E^c).$$ But, $$m^*(A^c)\leq m^*(E\cap A^c)+m^*(E^c\cap A^c)$$$$\implies m^*(A)\geq m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(A\cap E^c).$$

Hence, using sub-additivity of $m^*$ we have, $m^*(A)\geq m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(A\cap E^c)$, so $E$ is measurable.

> Note that we are using the following equivalent conditions:
>
> $(1)$ $E$ is measurable
>
> $(2)$ For every $Y\subseteq [0,1]$ we have $m^*(Y)\geq m^*(Y\cap
>  E)+m^*(E^c\cap Y)$.
>
> $(3)$ For every measurable set $A\subseteq [0,1]$ we have $m^*(A)\geq m^*(A\cap
>  E)+m^*(E^c\cap A)$.

Let us prove the non-trivial part, namely $(3)\implies (2)$. Let $Y\subseteq [0,1]$ and for a given $\varepsilon>0$ choose Lebesgue measurable subsets $A_1,A_2,...$ of $[0,1]$ so that $Y\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ with $m^*(Y)+\varepsilon>\sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(A_i)$.

Next, since we are assuming $(3)$ we have  $m(A_n)\geq m^*(A_n\cap E^c)+m^*(A_n\cap E)$. So, we have $$m^*(Y)+\varepsilon>\sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(A_i)$$$$\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(A_n\cap E^c)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(A_n\cap E)$$$$\geq m^*(Y\cap E)+m^*(Y\cap E^c).$$ Finally, letting $\varepsilon\to 0+$ we are done.

Comment: This shows that $m^*(A) = m^*(E \cap A) + m^*(A\cap E^c)$ for any measurable subset $A$. Does this imply easily that the same holds for *any* subset $A$?

Comment: Following @DánielG. question, doesn't this have to hold for any $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and not just for $A \subseteq [0,1]$?

Comment: I have edited, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @0-thUser So, what you are saying is it is true that $(1) \iff (2)$?.

Comment: Yes, if you want I can add these also.

Comment: @0-thUser It would be great if you could, I will try to prove them on my own and reference back to yours if you do so, thanks!

Comment: Nice. I am writing.

Comment: @0-thUser, could you prove that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$? Why is it not necessary that $(2)$ is valid for any $Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}\;?$

Comment: @Angelo Sure, why not. Note that $m^*$ is sub-additive implies $m^*(Y)\leq m^*(Y\cap E)+m^*(Y\cap E^*)$ for every $Y\subseteq [0,1]$.

Comment: Now, notice that in the definition of measurability we have equality sign, i.e. $E$ is measurable **iff** for every subset $Y$ we have $m^*(Y)= m^*(Y\cap E)+m^*(Y\cap E^*)$. So, we are done.

Comment: Okay, you are considering $\Bbb R$, **but note that here we have to consider a finite measure to hold the main result stated by OP**.

Comment: So, I am considering the space $\big([0,1], \mathcal A,m\big)$, where $\mathcal A$ is the set of all Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ and $m$ is the restriction of Lebesgue measure of $\Bbb R$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry, in the previous comments, I have made typos, please consider $E^c$ instead of $E^*$. **Also, throughout the answer and comments I am considering complement w.r.t. $[0,1]$.**

Comment: @0-thUser Could you include a proof that $(2) \implies (1)$. I can not seem to get it.

Comment: Note that $m^∗$ is sub-additive implies $m^∗(Y)≤m^∗(Y∩E)+m^∗(Y∩E^c)$ for every $Y⊆[0,1]$. Now, notice that in the definition of measurability we have equality sign, i.e. **we define** $E$ is to be  measurable if for every subset $Y$ of $[0,1]$ we have $m^∗(Y)=m^∗(Y∩E)+m^∗(Y∩E^c)$. So, we are done.

Comment: @Dalton, look at my answer, it contains a proof that $(2)\implies (1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$(2)\implies(1)$

**Proof:**

Assume that $\;E\;$ is a subset of $\;[0,1]\;$ such that (2) holds.

Let $\;Y\;$ be a $\;G_\delta\;$ set ($Y$ is Lebesgue measurable) such that $\;E\subseteq Y\subseteq [0,1]\;$ and $\;m(Y)=m^*(E)\;$.

From $\;(2)\;$ it follows that

$m^*(E)=m(Y)=m^*(Y)\ge m^*(Y\cap E)+m^*(Y\cap E^c)=$

$=m^*(E)+m^*(Y\cap E^c)\;,\;$ hence

$m^*(Y\cap E^c)=0\;$ and so $\;Z=Y\cap E^c\;$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Since $\;E=Y-Z\;,\;$ it is Lebesgue measurable as well.

**Addendum:**

Now we are going to prove that there exists a $\;G_\delta\;$ set $\;Y\;$ such that $\;E\subseteq Y\subseteq [0,1]\;$ and $\;m(Y)=m^*(E)\;$.

$m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty m(I_n): \left(I_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\text{ is a sequence of open}\\\text{ intervals such that } E\subseteq\bigcup_\limits{n=1}^\infty I_n\right\}.$

Let $\;A=\bigcup_\limits{n=1}^\infty I_n\implies A\;$ is a open set, $\;A\supseteq E\;$ and $\;m(A)\le\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty m(I_n)\;.$

There exists a sequence $\;\left(A_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ of open sets such that $\;A_k\supseteq E\;$ and $\;m(A_k)<m^*(E)+\cfrac{1}{k}\;,\;$ for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

Let $\;B_k=A_k\cap\left]-\frac{1}{k},1+\frac{1}{k}\right[\;$ for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

Hence,

$B_k\;$ is a open set, $\;E\subseteq B_k\subseteq\left]-\frac{1}{k},1+\frac{1}{k}\right[\;$ and $\;m(B_k)<m^*(E)+\cfrac{1}{k}\;,\;$ for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

Let $\;Y=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty B_k\implies Y\;$ is a $\;G_\delta\;$ set.

It results that $\;E\subseteq Y\subseteq\left]-\frac{1}{k},1+\frac{1}{k}\right[\;$ for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

so $\;E\subseteq Y\subseteq[0,1]\;,\;$ moreover,

$m(Y)<m^*(E)+\cfrac{1}{k}\;$ for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}\;,\;$ hence

$\;m(Y)\le m^*(E)\;.$

Since $\;E\subseteq Y\;,\;$ it follows that $\;m^*(E)\le m(Y)\;,\;$ hence $\;m(Y)=m^*(E)\;.$

Comment: Nice! I went down this route but I didn’t know that we could guarantee a $G_{\delta}$-set between E and [0,1]...could you explain why we can?

Comment: @Dalton, look at the addendum.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.